# Problem getting Youtube Data API v3 OAuth2 token using REST endpoints

Tags: javascript, react-native, rest, youtube-data-api

I have been trying to get an YouTube OAuth2 token in react native using the following code:

```
let url =
  'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?' +
  new URLSearchParams({
    client_id: encodeURIComponent(clientId),
    redirect_uri: encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:19006/oauth2callback'),
    scope: encodeURIComponent('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'),
    response_type: 'token'
  });

//Fetch the URL
fetch(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    // Log and return the response as JSON
    let rJson = response.json();
    console.log(rJson);
    return rJson;
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    // Log the API data
    console.log('token', data);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    // Log any errors
    console.log('something went wrong', err);
  });
```

I am getting the error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'
```

I have been stuck on this for ages even after looking at the [YouTube Data API Client-side Web Apps Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps) no doubt it's something simple I don't see but help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please acknowledge that the response of the endpoint you're calling is not JSON but HTML; the endpoint call's purpose is to [redirect you to Google's OAuth 2.0 server](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps#oauth-2.0-endpoints_1) that initiates the OAuth authorization flow.

Comment: Ohhh I see I didn't realise that, that would be the problem! Thanks :)